# RAID partition corrupted, maybe MegaRAID Storage Manager is to blame?

Tags: gpt, megaraid-storage-manager

We have a server with a Broadcom 9361-8i connected to two arrays, one pair of 14TB SAS SSDs in RAID 1 and four magnetic SAS drives in RAID 10, and everything worked fined for three years. I was trying to check the SMART info on these drives, so I installed the MegaRAID Storage Manager (MSM), and successfully used StorCLI to check the SMART data, and all was well for all six drives. OS is RHEL 8.4.

However, the next time I rebooted, the partition with the SSDs did not mount (neither is a boot partition; I boot from an M.2 drive that isn't connected to this RAID controller). The magnetic partition mounted just fine. Things I tried:

`#fdisk -l`

```
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 262144 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x64656c69

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           1 4294967295 4294967295   2T 74 unknown

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary
```

There is no sign of a partition table or Linux filesystem, just the nonsense 2TB DOS partition above. The MegaRAID BIOS utility shows everything as fine on the hardware side, recognizing two 14TB drives in a RAID 1 array.

`fsck` was fruitless, because it doesn't see a file system it is capable of checking.

`gparted` just sees a giant 14TB unallocated partition:
[gparted screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhCVo.png)

Data Rescue within gparted was on track to take about two weeks, so I scrapped that. Interestingly, that started at 2TB and was working its way toward 14TB.

I uninstalled/deleted MSM and rebooted to no avail, so perhaps that wasn't related to my problem? There was a power failure (no surge) that caused the shutdown prior to this partition error, but if that caused some issue with the SSDs wouldn't that show up in the MegaRAID BIOS utility?

Finally, I tried `testdisk`:

```
Disk /dev/sda - 15 TB / 13 TiB - CHS 1867708 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
 P EFI System                  2048    1230847    1228800 [EFI System Partition] [NO NAME]
 P Linux filesys. data      1230848    3327999    2097152
>P Linux filesys. data      3328000 30004738047 30001410048
```

The last one is 14TB and looks like my missing partition? My options are:

```
Keys A: add partition, L: load backup, T: change type, 
     Enter: to continue
```

EDIT-I selected Write partition at the next prompt, which resolved my issue.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Writing the partition info found using `testdisk` then rebooting solved my issue. I still can't prove that MegaRAID Storage Manager caused the problem in the first place, but I'm not eager to replicate to find out.